# Oracle SQL - trigger is mutating

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to create an after trigger that will call procedure and function to calculate the area of the room.

Procedure and function work correctly when existing `customer_room_id` is passed. If they are called by the trigger I get error

> "table CUSTOMER_ROOMS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_display_floor_area
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON customer_rooms
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.room_size.length IS NOT NULL OR NEW.room_size.width IS NOT NULL)

DECLARE
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
  vn_customer_room_id customer_rooms.customer_room_id%TYPE := :NEW.customer_room_id;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer room id ' || vn_customer_room_id);
  proc_display_floor_area(vn_customer_room_id);
END trig_display_floor_area;
/
SHOW ERRORS;                                                   

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_display_floor_area (in_customer_room_id customer_rooms.customer_room_id%TYPE) IS

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(func_get_room_customer_name(in_customer_room_id) || '''S room with id ' || in_customer_room_id || ' has floor area ' || func_floor_area(in_customer_room_id) || 'm2');
END proc_display_floor_area;
/
SHOW ERRORS;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_floor_area (in_customer_room_id customer_rooms.customer_room_id%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
vn_width customer_rooms.room_size.width%TYPE;
vn_lenght customer_rooms.room_size.length%TYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT cr.room_size.width
  INTO vn_width
  FROM customer_rooms cr
  WHERE customer_room_id = in_customer_room_id;

  SELECT cr.room_size.length
  INTO vn_lenght
  FROM customer_rooms cr
  WHERE customer_room_id = in_customer_room_id;

  RETURN ROUND(vn_lenght * vn_width / 10000, 2);
END func_floor_area;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: A *table* is mutating, not the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to select from the table ( `customer_rooms` ) that owns the `Trigger`

So, instead of fetching the values of `length` and `width` again within the function, you may pass them from the `TRIGGER`

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION func_floor_area (in_width  customer_rooms.room_size.width%TYPE,
                                            in_length customer_rooms.room_size.length%TYPE
)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN ROUND(in_length * in_width / 10000, 2);
END func_floor_area;
/
```

So, within your `TRIGGER`, call the function as

`func_get_room_customer_name(:NEW.room_size.width, :NEW.room_size.length );`

In my opinion, you don't need a separate procedure and a function to do these. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is not a reliable method to see the output from a `Trigger`. Use a logging table instead to save the value returned from the function. Or simply calculate the area

```
ROUND(:NEW.room_size.length * :NEW.room_size.width/ 10000, 2);
```

and save it into another table `AREA` with an `INSERT INTO` within the `Trigger`.

A totally different option is if you can afford to create a column in the same table called `area` as a `virtual column`, using the `column_name [datatype] [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)`, something like

```
AREA NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROUND ( room_size.length * room_size.width / 10000, 2)
```

,the `Trigger` itself could be totally avoided.